# Sort very large text file in PowerShell

Tags: sorting, powershell, text, large-files

I have standard Apache log files, between 500Mb and 2GB in size. I need to sort the lines in them (each line starts with a date yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss, so no treatment necessary for sorting.

The simplest and most obvious thing that comes to mind is

```
 Get-Content unsorted.txt | sort | get-unique > sorted.txt
```

I am guessing (without having tried it) that doing this using `Get-Content` would take forever in my 1GB files. I don't quite know my way around `System.IO.StreamReader`, but I'm curious if an efficient solution could be put together using that?

Thanks to anyone who might have a more efficient idea.

[edit]

I tried this subsequently, and it took a very long time; some 10 minutes for 400MB.

Comment: I tried the command above and it indeed took a long time (about 10 minutes on 460MB), and the final result wasn't what I needed, plus the target file (`sorted.txt`) ended up twice the size of teh source.

Comment: The size differences is probably because of different encodings being used. Replacing the `> sorted.txt` with something like `| Set-Content sorted.txt` might do the trick, otherwise you could try `| Out-File sorted.txt -Encoding <your choice>`.

Comment: Using your suggestion `| Set-Content sorted.txt` helped sort it out correctly, but it is still quite slow. Adding `-ReadCount 5000` after `Get-Content` makes is much faster, but the sorting is broken. I'm guessing, in order to properly sort, we have to read line by line, rather than a block at a time... I wish there were a more efficient way.

Comment: FYI; this isn't something I've tested, I'm merely relying on logics. If I'm wrong I'll gladly be corrected - I don't mind learning... :) For the uniqueness, if the first line and the last of a 10K line file were duplicates (seems improbable in a log file that most likely appends) you might be forced to store all of it in memory before being able to sort out only the unique lines. The unsorted stuff you're experiencing has to be in chunks of 5000 lines, like with having the first 5000 lines appearing after lines 5001-10000 in a 10K line file. Each chunk of 5K lines should be sorted though.

Comment: @notjustme : the log entries are presumably unique. This is a standard Apache access log file, recording access to the web server, so no two records are the same (there should be at least a fraction of a second of difference for two consecutive requests from the same IP and with same other parametres).

Comment: May I ask (and perhaps I should have led with this), just what are you trying to sort and find unique lines for if date and time isn't unique in itself? I haven't checked any Apache logs out recently (a few years) so I can't see what the problem is...

Comment: The logs I receive don't come directly from one server. They are consolidated from several sources, and there are times when the individual lines in the log aren't consecutive. For example, first few lines may be for access at 2015-08-11 23:58:01, then the lines that follow it may start from 2015-08-11 00:01:15, then again for 5015-08-11 23:58:26. WebTrends needs all log lines to be sorted by their time stamp, otherwise, it will ignore entries with timestamp older than those it already analysed.

Comment: You should measure reading and sorting time separately. I'd guess that reading part is slow.

Comment: BTW - you can use the `-Unique` parameter on Sort-Object to achieve the same thing as piping the results through Get-Unique.

Comment: I actually just tried Measure-Command on the version with `gc file.txt | sort | get-unique` versus `gc file.txt | sort -Unique` and the second version was significantly faster (I'm guessing because you remove the overhead of the extra pipeline).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Get-Content` is terribly ineffective for reading large files. `Sort-Object` is not very fast, too.

Let's set up a base line:

```
$sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();
$c = Get-Content .\log3.txt -Encoding Ascii
$sw.Stop();
Write-Output ("Reading took {0}" -f $sw.Elapsed);

$sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();
$s = $c | Sort-Object;
$sw.Stop();
Write-Output ("Sorting took {0}" -f $sw.Elapsed);

$sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();
$u = $s | Get-Unique
$sw.Stop();
Write-Output ("uniq took {0}" -f $sw.Elapsed);

$sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();
$u | Out-File 'result.txt' -Encoding ascii
$sw.Stop();
Write-Output ("saving took {0}" -f $sw.Elapsed);
```

With a 40 MB file having 1.6 million lines (made of 100k unique lines repeated 16 times) this script produces the following output on my machine:

```
Reading took 00:02:16.5768663
Sorting took 00:02:04.0416976
uniq took 00:01:41.4630661
saving took 00:00:37.1630663
```

Totally unimpressive: more than 6 minutes to sort tiny file. Every step can be improved a lot. Let's use `StreamReader` to read file line by line into `HashSet` which will remove duplicates, then copy data to `List` and sort it there, then use `StreamWriter` to dump results back.

```
$hs = new-object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]
$sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("D:\log3.txt")
try {
    while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
    {
        $t = $hs.Add($line)
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
$sw.Stop();
Write-Output ("read-uniq took {0}" -f $sw.Elapsed);

$sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();
$ls = new-object system.collections.generic.List[string] $hs;
$ls.Sort();
$sw.Stop();
Write-Output ("sorting took {0}" -f $sw.Elapsed);

$sw = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();
try
{
    $f = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter "d:\result2.txt";
    foreach ($s in $ls)
    {
        $f.WriteLine($s);
    }
}
finally
{
    $f.Close();
}
$sw.Stop();
Write-Output ("saving took {0}" -f $sw.Elapsed);
```

this script produces:

```
read-uniq took 00:00:32.2225181
sorting took 00:00:00.2378838
saving took 00:00:01.0724802
```

On same input file it runs more than 10 times faster. I am still surprised though it takes 30 seconds to read file from disk.

Comment: Give Measure-Command a try: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh849910.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This is a significant performance improvement, however, the target file is noticeably smaller than the source. Duplicate entries seem deleted, which I don't want it to do. All I need it to do is sort the lines alphabetically; if there are multiple identical lines, keep them all. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your sample code called `Get-Unique` which removes duplicates. If you don't need it, then just read directly to `List` and sort, no need to use `HashSet` here.

Comment: Perhaps file read improves if file is read as a whole, not line by line.

Comment: @JakubP, I highly doubt that. Breaking into lines have to happen at some point, either while reading from disk, or while reading from memory, and I expect buffering will make the difference between those two negligible.

Comment: This is not powershell. It is C#.

Answer (score 3):

I've grown to hate this part of windows powershell, it is a memory hog on these larger files. One trick is to read the lines `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines('file.txt') | sort -u | out-file file2.txt -encoding ascii`

Another trick, seriously is to just use linux.

`cat file.txt | sort -u > output.txt`

Linux is so insanely fast at this, it makes me wonder what the heck microsoft is thinking with this set up.

It may not be feasible in all cases, and i understand, but if you have a linux machine, you can copy 500 megs to it, sort and unique it, and copy it back in under a couple minutes.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited to be more clear based on n0rd's comments)

It's might be a memory issue. Since you're loading the entire file into memory to sort it (and adding the overhead of the pipe into Sort-Object and the pipe into Get-Unique), it's possible that you're hitting the memory limits of the machine and forcing it to page to disk, which will slow things down a lot. One thing you might consider is splitting the logs up before sorting them, and then splicing them back together.

This probably won't match your format exactly, but if I've got a large log file for, say, 8/16/2012 which spans several hours, I can split it up into a different file for each hour using something like this:

```
for($i=0; $i -le 23; $i++){ Get-Content .\u_ex120816.log | ? { $_ -match "^2012-08-16 $i`:" } | Set-Content -Path "$i.log" }
```

This is creating a regular expression for each hour of that day and dumping all the matching log entries into a smaller log file named by the hour (e.g. 16.log, 17.log).

Then I can run your process of sorting and getting unique entries on a much smaller subsets, which should run a lot faster:

```
 for($i=0; $i -le 23; $i++){ Get-Content "$i.log" | sort | get-unique > "$isorted.txt" }
```

And then you can splice them back together.

Depending on the frequency of the logs, it might make more sense to split them by day, or minute; the main thing is to get them into more manageable chunks for sorting.

Again, this only makes sense if you're hitting the memory limits of the machine (or if Sort-Object is using a really inefficient algorithm).

Comment: sorting one large chunk is not slower than several smaller chunks, provided all data fits into memory (i.e. nothing spills to swap)

Comment: @n0rd - it would depend on the size of the file, how much memory the machine has available, the algorithm Sort-Object uses, and how close to sorted the data is beforehand.

Comment: On same input data sorting whole set would never be slower than sorting chunks with same algorithm and then merging. For external sorting (when all data does not fit into memory), yes, you have to split, sort and merge. Otherwise there is no gain to do so.

Comment: Revision: above is true for any decent (O(nlogn) time complexity) sorting algorithm (otherwise they could be sped up by splitting, sorting and merging), but not true for any worse algorithms. I am pretty sure Sort-Object uses something decent. Pushing data through pipeline may contribute a lot to execution time, though.

Comment: I'll update my answer to be more clear about the (potential) problem it's fixing.

Answer (score 0):

If each line of the log is prefixed with a timestamp, and the log messages don't contain embedded newlines (which would require special handling), I think it would take less memory and execution time to convert the timestamp from `[String]` to `[DateTime]` before sorting.  The following assumes each log entry is of the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss: <Message>` (note that the [`HH` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#HH_Specifier) is used for a 24-hour clock):

```
Get-Content unsorted.txt
    | ForEach-Object {
        # Ignore empty lines; can substitute with [String]::IsNullOrWhitespace($_) on PowerShell 3.0 and above
        if (-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_))
        {
            # Split into at most two fields, even if the message itself contains ': '
            [String[]] $fields = $_ -split ': ', 2;

            return New-Object -TypeName 'PSObject' -Property @{
                Timestamp = [DateTime] $fields[0];
                Message   = $fields[1];
            };
        }
    } | Sort-Object -Property 'Timestamp', 'Message';
```

If you are processing the input file for interactive display purposes you can pipe the above into `Out-GridView` or `Format-Table` to view the results.  If you need to save the sorted results you can pipe the above into the following:

```
    | ForEach-Object {
        # Reconstruct the log entry format of the input file
        return '{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}: {1}' -f $_.Timestamp, $_.Message;
    } `
    | Out-File -Encoding 'UTF8' -FilePath 'sorted.txt';
```

Answer (score 0):

"Get-Content" can be faster than you think. Check this code-snippet in addition to the above solution:

```
foreach ($block in (get-content $file -ReadCount 100)) {
    foreach ($line in $block){[void] $hs.Add($line)}
}
```

Comment: Of course it is not as fast as a StreamReader or a [System.IO.File]::OpenText but on the other hand it does not create any peak-load on the file-system when using it in blocks.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a great way to do it in powershell, including `[IO.File]::ReadLines()`, but with the native windows sort.exe or the gnu sort.exe, either within cmd.exe, 30 million random numbers can be sorted in about 5 minutes with around 1 gb of ram.  The gnu sort automatically breaks things up into temp files to save ram.  Both commands have options to start the sort at a certain character column.  Gnu sort can merge sorted files.  See [external sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).

30 million line test file:

```
& { foreach ($i in 1..300kb) { get-random } } | set-content file.txt
```

And then in cmd:

```
copy file.txt+file.txt file2.txt
copy file2.txt+file2.txt file3.txt
copy file3.txt+file3.txt file4.txt
copy file4.txt+file4.txt file5.txt
copy file5.txt+file5.txt file6.txt
copy file6.txt+file6.txt file7.txt
copy file7.txt+file7.txt file8.txt
```

With gnu sort.exe from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm .  Don't forget the dependency dll's -- libiconv2.dll & libintl3.dll.  Within cmd.exe:

```
.\sort.exe < file8.txt > filesorted.txt
```

Or windows sort.exe within cmd.exe:

```
sort.exe < file8.txt > filesorted.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With the function below:

```
PS> PowerSort -SrcFile C:\windows\win.ini
```

```
function PowerSort {
    param(
        [string]$SrcFile = "",
        [string]$DstFile = "",
        [switch]$Force
    )

    if ($SrcFile -eq "") {
        write-host "USAGE: PowerSort -SrcFile (srcfile)  [-DstFile (dstfile)] [-Force]"
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        $SrcFileFullPath = Resolve-Path $SrcFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable _frperror        
        if (-not($SrcFileFullPath)) {
            throw "Source file not found: $SrcFile";
        }
    }

    [Collections.Generic.List[string]]$lines = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($SrcFileFullPath)
    
    $lines.Sort();

    # Write Sorted File to Pipe
    if ($DstFile -eq "") {
        foreach ($line in $lines) {
            write-output $line
        }           
    }
    
    # Write Sorted File to File
    else {
        $pipe_enable = 0;
        $DstFileFullPath = Resolve-Path $DstFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ev

        # Destination File doesn't exist        
        if (-not($DstFileFullPath)) {
           $DstFileFullPath = $ev[0].TargetObject       
        }
        
        # Destination Exists and -force not specified.
        elseif (-not $Force) {
            throw "Destination file already exists: ${DstFile}  (using -Force Flag to overwrite)"           
        }       
        
        write-host "Writing-File: $DstFile"
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($DstFileFullPath, $lines)
    }
    return
}
```