# How can I remove duplicates in Powershell without running out of memory?

Tags: powershell

I'm currently using this command in Windows Powershell to remove duplicates from a simple 1 row CSV.

```
gc combine.csv | sort | get-unique > tags.cs
```

Whenever I run it on a 150mb CSV (20 million row *guessing*) the task manager shows the Powershell eating up all available memory (32GB) and then using virtual memory. I also let the script run for about an hour as well and it didn't finish. I find that as strange because in excel it usually takes a few seconds to remove duplicates from my 1M row CSVS. Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Comment: At risk of stating the obvious... Use Excel.

Comment: That would be the preferable option, however, Excel has a 1.2M row limit.

Comment: for anyone curious to go and find out why it uses so much RAM and submit fixes ;) -- [sort-object code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/e9d5f68ba521177c72dbe7c4ec2c37b5c7f728d1/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/sort-object.cs) and [Get-Unique code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/a3786158ca51cd65388743f900b69ec9e253c3d9/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/GetUnique.cs)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler really interesting that `sort -unique` uses a `SortedSet` when used with partial results (`-Top` and `-Bottom`). There's a comment in there that says it might be worth using it for `-Unique` as well.

Comment: After some discussion on the PowerShell slack, as well as being slow, what `Get-Content` is doing is adding `NoteProperties` to every single line in the file, with `PSChildName, PSDrive, PSParentPath, PSPath, PSProvider, ReadCount` extra data. 2 of them being `[PSDriveInfo]` and `[ProviderInfo]` objects, not strings. 20 million times that lot could well account for a lot of the memory. `-ReadCount` may help reduce that by reading several lines at once, but needs extra processing to unbundle them. ( @briantist )

Answer (score 8):

You could try:

```
Get-Content combine.csv -ReadCount 1000 | 
    foreach-object { $_ } | 
    Sort-Object -Unique | 
    Set-Content tags.cs
```

(`gc combine.csv -read 1kb | % { $_ } | sort -uniq | sc tags.cs`)

But I think you'll hit the same problems. If you want faster results, and they don't need to be sorted they just need to be duplicate free:

```
$Lines = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new()


$Lines.UnionWith([string[]][System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines('c:\path\to\combine.csv'))


[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines('c:\path\to\tags.cs', $Lines)
```

That ran on my test 20M random numbers file in 23 seconds and ~1.5GB memory. If they do need to be sorted, use `SortedSet` instead of `HashSet`, that ran in 5 minutes and <2GB memory. While your code is still running and currently passing 15GB.

Edit: **tiberriver256** comments that `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` can be streamed before the file has finished being read; it returns an enumerator rather than a final array of all lines. In the HashSet case this knocks runtime down a little from 12.5s to 11.5s - it varies too much to be sure, but it does seem to help.

Comment: Just discovered [this interesting piece](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) on `readLines` vs `readAllLines`: _The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient._

Comment: @tiberriver256 oh interesting! I assumed `readlines` was for some lines, but not all of them. Yes it returns `IEnumerable<string>` and `ReadAllLines` returns `string[]`. And `UnionWith` can work with an IEnumerable too. Pity I just deleted my test file, so I can't test it like for like.

Comment: I'd be curious to see what your comparison is on casting the hashset to a list and then calling the sort method vs a SortedSet. On my tests the List and sort was way faster than a sorted set.

Comment: @tiberriver256 that's a good idea; new test file, 20M lines of random numbers, ~19.9M unique and ~100k dupes. `SortedSet` and `UnionWith` -> 317 seconds, about what I got before. I just noticed that SortedSet can be initialised from an IEnumerable, so `[Collections.Generic.SortedSet[string]]::new([IO.File]::ReadLines($file))` - predicted it would be the same, it's terrible -> 2222 seconds, 37 minutes(!). Your approach to cast to `Generic.List[string]` and `Sort()` -> **134** seconds. Way faster!

Answer (score 5):

Excel is designed to deal with files that large efficiently (apparently? I'm actually a little surprised).

The major problem with your code is that you're sorting it. I know you're doing that because `Get-Unique` requires it, but the way that `Sort-Object` works is that it needs to collect every item being sent into it (in this case every line of the file) in memory in order to actually do the sort. <s>And unlike your file, it's not just storing it as flat memory, it's storing it as *N* strings where *N* is the number of lines in your file, and all the overhead of those in-memory strings.</s> As TessellatingHeckler points out, it seems to be tied much more to the sorting than the storing!

You probably want to be determining whether a given line is unique as you process it, so you can discard it right away.

For that, I'll recommend Sets. In particular a [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) or, if you actually need it sorted, a [SortedSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx).

A simple conversion of your code:

```
Get-Content combine.csv | 
    ForEach-Object -Begin { 
        $h = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]]::new() 
    } -Process { 
        if ($h.Add($_)) {
            $_
        }
    } |
    Set-Content tags.cs
```

For me, testing this on a > 650 MB file with ~4M lines where only 26 were unique took just over a minute and didn't appreciably affect RAM.

The same file where about half the rows were unique took around 2 minutes, and used about 2 GB of RAM (with `SortedSet` it took a little over 2.5 mins and about 2.4 GB).

That same latter file, even with simplifying down from `| sort | gu` to `| sort -Unique` used over 5 GB of RAM in ~10 seconds.

You can probably squeeze more performance out if you start using `StreamReader.ReadLine` and `for` loops, and some other things, but I'll leave that an exercise for you.

It seems that in most implementations, in the best case, the amount of RAM used is going to be highly dependent on how many of the items are unique (with more unique items meaning more RAM).

Comment: Excel is not designed for millions of rows. Its absolute maximum allowable rows is 1,048,576 rows per worksheet, at which point you are already two or three orders of magnitude past appropriate "spreadsheet" size and should be working with a database of some kind, whether it's Access or a SQL-based approach.

Answer (score 4):

Get-Content and stdio `>` are both pretty slow. .Net will likely give you much better performance.

Try:

```
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "tags.csv"
[System.IO.File]::ReadLines("combine.csv") | get-unique | sort | % { $Stream.writeline($_) }
$Stream.close()
```

Testing on my own box with a 4 column 1,000,000 row csv I hit 650MB of memory utilization at 22 seconds. Running the same csv with get-content and `>` was 2GB of memory and 60 seconds.

With some additional trickiness taken from a similar question here ([Sort very large text file in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385611/sort-very-large-text-file-in-powershell)) you can further reduce the time by casting the data to a hashset to get unique values and then to a list and running the sort method as this seems to be a bit faster than PowerShell's Sort-Object.

```
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "tags.csv"
$UniqueItems = [system.collections.generic.list[string]]([System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]([System.IO.File]::ReadLines("combine.csv")))
$UniqueItems.sort()
$UniqueItems | % { $Stream.writeline($_) }
$Stream.close()
```

Using this on my same dataset I was able to do it in 1 second with 144MB of memory usage.

Comment: Using `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()` is a good idea, but note that `Get-Unique` only works on _already sorted_ input. You can, however, use `Sort-Object -Unique`.