# Powershell Performance

Tags: performance, powershell

i have a Problem with powershell Performance while searching a 40gb log file.
i Need to check if any of 1000 email adresses are included in this 40gb file. This would take 180 hours :D any ideas?

```
$logFolder = "H:\log.txt"
$adressen= Get-Content H:\Adressen.txt
$ergebnis = @()

foreach ($adr in $adressen){
    $suche =  Select-String -Path $logFolder -Pattern "\[\(\'from\'\,.*$adr.*\'\)\]" -List
    $aktiv= $false
    $adr
    if ($suche){
        $aktiv = $true 
    }

    if ($aktiv -eq $true){
        $ergebnis+=$adr + ";Ja"
    }
    else{
        $ergebnis+=$adr + ";Nein"
    }
}
$ergebnis |Out-File H:\output.txt
```

Comment: there is one BIG problem that i see ... you are using `+=` on an array. that makes a NEW array with every add. try switching to a generic.list and using the `.Add()` method instead.

Comment: Get-Content is very inefficient with large files (I'm surprised that you can actually load this file using Get-Content). Using the System.IO classes and streaming the data should also increase the speed of your script (with a good optimized script you can get the runtime down from 180 hours to maybe 1 hour, depending on the speed of your storage).

Comment: The Problem is not the Speed of writing the Array, but searching the log file. The search of one adress in "adresses.txt" on the mail.log takes more then 10 minutes. Bluuf is right i think. Need to make a Research now on how to do this in powershell. i can just do easy Little scripts at the Moment. maybe some1 can help a bit?

Comment: You are looping a 40GB file 1000 times so you are essentially reading 40TB of data. I would try too [sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32418662/52598) your logfile on unique entries, sort your addresses and perform a mergejoin between the two.

Comment: What is the structure of your log file? is it csv?

Answer (score 1):

Don't read the file 1000 times.

Build a regexp line with all 1000 addresses (it's gonna be a huge line, but hey, much smaller than 40TB). Like:

```
$Pattern  = "\[\(\'from\'\,.*$( $adressen -join '|' ).*\'\)\]"
```

Then do your Select-String, and save the result to do an address-by-address search in it. Hopefully, the result will be much smaller than 40Gb, and should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, replace

```
$ergebnis = @()
```

with

```
$ergebnis = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
```

and

```
$ergebnis+=$adr + ";Ja"
```

with

```
$ergebnis.add("$adr;Ja")
```

or respective

```
$ergebnis.add("$adr;Nein")
```

This will speed up your script quite a bit.

Comment: While it's generally a good idea to avoid iteratively "extending" an array with `=+`, it is not the OP's problem, given that only 1000 elements are added to the array; try `(Measure-Command { $a = @(); foreach ($i in 1..1000) { $a += 'foo' } }).TotalSeconds`, and you'll see that it takes very little time. The OP's problem is calling `Select-String` 1000 times on a huge file.